# python LDAP modify password

Tags: python, passwords, ldap

I have a Windows 2012 R2 server and a LDAP server on it. I wrote a python script to modify the password of user (the user, who isn't admin, want to modify is own password. I have an other function which modify the password when you're admin, but I don't want to set a password, but modify it). This is a sample of my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf-8

import ldap
import ldap.modlist as modlist

ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
ld = ldap.initialize('ldaps://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:636')
ld.simple_bind_s('XXXXXX@ad2012.local', 'XXXXXXX')

new = {'unicodePwd':[str('"XXXXXXXX"').decode('utf8').encode('utf-16-le')]}
old = {'unicodePwd':[str('"YYYYYYYY"').decode('utf8').encode('utf-16-le')]}

ldif = modlist.modifyModlist(old, new)
ld.modify_s('A DN',ldif)
```

But when I run it, I have an error :

> ldap.CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION: {'info': '0000052D: AtrErr: DSID-03191083, #1:\n\t0: 0000052D: DSID-03191083, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 9005a (unicodePwd)\n', 'desc': 'Constraint violation'}

I tried with decode/encode or without. passwd_s() is not working either.
I searched a lot on google, I found a lot of solutions for others people, but not working for me.

If someone could help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message part you want to focus on is `'info': '0000052D`. The hex value `0000052D` translates to a system error code of decimal 1325. That error code is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> ERROR_PASSWORD_RESTRICTION
>
> 1325 (0x52D)
>
> Unable to update the password. The value provided for the new password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirements
>   of the domain.

So it appears the new password you are trying to set somehow violates the password policy assigned to the user.

Comment: Apparently, even if I give a very long password, with numbers, capitals letters and symbols, I always have the same problem... My user isn't in any groups. I can only change his password if I'm administrator...

Comment: Thanks, it was a problem with the GPO. I change them. Now, I have an 0x56 error but well, I progress !

Comment: Can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982547/ldap3-python-modify-replace-an-object-with-filter