# ldap3 python modify replace an object with filter

Tags: python, ldap, ldap3

How can we filter when applying ldapmodify?

For eg: this is how my user object looks like:

`dn: mail=abc@d.com,ou=users,dc=dev,dc=com
sn: po
givenName: abc
pin: 1234
mail: abc@d.com
telephoneNumber: 11234567890
enabled: FALSE
city: city
cn: abc@d.com
o: org`

I want to modify this user's city if his org is org. How can I apply such a filter?

I am doing it using ldap3, do I need to use controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the *Assertion Control* along with your modify operation (see [RFC 4528](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4528)). Basically the control contains a filter which has to be matched.

I'm using this control in my [web2ldap](https://web2ldap.de) to prevent concurrent writes to do anything bad.

I have some doubts that [ldap3](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io) module supports it out-of-the-box though.

Further notes:

- Not all LDAP servers support this control.
- There are subtle bugs in LDAP server implementations supporting this control.